# Debug ASP.NET CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, content-management-system

We're developing a custom Content Management System in ASP.NET 4.0, using Team Foundation Server for source control. The database is hosted in a remote server, whereas the debug is done locally, thus new content (aspx pages) created by each member of the team is stored in our local computers and unavailable for other team members. I don't think adding those files to source control is the best approach, but the only other way I see is deploying to an external IIS for debugging.
Have you already worked with this scenario? Wwhat do you think is the best option? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thus new content (aspx pages) created by each member of the team is stored in our local computers and unavailable for other team members ... I don't think adding those files to source control is the best approach

I really wonder why you think that is a bad idea... I think adding created code in your source control system is the very best thing to do.

What do you think happens if a computer stops working, gets stolen, etc? How do you obtain the file again? Store every file that is crucial to your system in a source control system.

Comment: what I wanted to mean with new created content is the pages we create on the fly for testing purposes while debugging, which are actually not part of the CMS itself and wont be given to the customer as deliverables.

Comment: Why not? You can still check them in, just don't deliver them to the customer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have a "tools" folder in project structure where you keep all of your test pages. Then when project is built that folder can be excluded from copying.

For example when Release build is executed "tools" folder is excluded, while Debug builds leave it in the project.

It really depends how do you guys work, how many of you there are, how often do you do delivery cycle - but generally garbage of test pages tends to grow all over the place (same as commented out code) if there is no systematic approach and whole project team chips in.